# A gun camouflaged as nerf shooters?

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons, assassination

So I thought about the possibility of an assassination in my story where the assassin camouflaged his gun as a nerf blaster. would that be possible?

Comment: Extremely possible.

Comment: Did this really need to be asked? Was common sense not enough to figure this out? "Is it possible?" questions in general are not good questions because the answers are overly simple and overly broad.

Comment: @DKNguyen there's nothing wrong with "is this possible?" in general, but _any_ question  where the answer is so unambiguously obvious seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @DKNguyen Not really pointless depending on the competencies of the assassin.  For starters, the plastics in nerf guns are not nearly as tough as the materials in a real gun; so, you have to worry about the hand grip breaking when fired.  Then there is the question of how to conceal the chamber, how easily the nerf gun can be disassembled and put back together, how you can aim it, etc.  That said, I think this question would be much better framed as how easy would it be than if it could be done.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Feasibility/practicality questions are completely different than possibility questions

Comment: @thequestioner Useful details would be: What kind of gun are you trying to conceal, what is the technical level of expertise available to the assassin, and how far away are you tring shoot, and how close of scrutiny does the gun need to pass (is it just a toy in a crowd, are there police checkpoint, are there metal detectors, etc.)

Comment: In a frame challenge comment: just why? We have evidence of guns camouflaged as books, briefcases, canes, belt buckles, watches, cellphones etc, so why would an assassin who's trying to conceal his gun make it look like a nerf gun? They're clanky, normally large and not at all something you'll often see people carrying on their person, and sounds especially bad when you consider policemen around the world have shot children wielding actual toy guns, which leads me to believe they'd react similarly when the wielder is an adult who normally wouldn't have one on them to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

It is obviously possible.

It is also something people have thought of before: from snopes, [Shotgun Disguised as Water Gun or Super Soaker](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/hiding-shotgun/).

[image: Fake picture of real gun disguised as toy gun]

(probably fake).

I'm sure similar rumours have popped up about paintball guns, and the reason why plenty of paintball centres don't have red pellets, etc.

Honestly, given the tendency of police in some parts of the world to [shoot children wielding toy guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Tamir_Rice), I'm not sure it is a particularly good way to conceal a weapon.

Answer (score 4):

People are inventing ways to hide guns since guns were invented, look at this [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/ArtefactPorn/comments/l81djg/a_gun_hidden_within_a_bible_made_for_francesco/)

> A gun hidden within a bible, made for Francesco Morozini, Doge of Venice (1619-1694). The owner of the bible could pull the silk bookmark to shoot while the book was still closed. Now on display at the Museo Correr in Venice

[image]

A nerf blaster is just a big plastic container, making one to fit a gun would be pretty easy. The only difficulty would be to get a correct aim, but that's of limited concern if the gun is supposed to be shot at close range.

Comment: I do like the trick oif using a bookmark to trigger the weapon. I wonder if you can fire a flintlock like that when it is on its side. It seems like it _should_ be possible, but I can see that it might be more inclined to misfire...

Answer (score 3):

#### Bad Idea - but like many bad ideas, you can 3D print it at home!

I'm not going to link to the final product or modify the OpenSCAD source to do this because I don't feel like getting SWAT'd. But it's trivial - if you really want to do this you'll need to learn the 5 commands yourself from the tutorials included.

Download a ready-to-print nerf gun from thingiverse with the full openSCAD source, eg:

[image]

Download a 3D model of your real gun. Gun makers in the USA often provide high detail models and low-poly ones for game developers free of charge so they can get some sweet product placement.

Use the entry level CSG operations that you're taught in the tutorial in OpenSCAD to create a cavity to hold the gun.

Recompile the OpenSCAD project so all the individual parts are regenerated respecting your new cavity, export them as STL files, print in pretty colours, and assemble it.

Install a screw in the plastic trigger such that pulling it depresses the real trigger, you may need to angle-grind off trigger guard.

Note that as soon as you point this at someone, especially in the USA, they'll assume its a deadly weapon and slaughter you anyway, why?

#### Real guns come in pretty colours!

[image]

There are much better ways to disguise a gun than **AS A GUN!**

Comment: How unreasonable is this new fear of being killed by a *Hello Kitty* branded item?

Comment: @PipperChip They're illegal to import into Australia, so I'm safe. You on the other hand, could be very reasonable.